# Not show toolbar text

Tags: visual-studio-code

As you can see in the screenshot below, the file menu, edit, view and others are not visible. The menus themselves open and perform their function. The problem appeared after the upgrade to code_1.29.1-1542309157_amd64. What actions should I take to restore text visibility in the toolbar?
PS // Delete and reinstall the result did not yield (including purge).
[image]

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/62593

Comment: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/15194